# iCloud storage photos

Tags: ios, icloud, iphone

I have an iphone 4, with ios 7.1.2, and my phone tells me my software is up to date. When I log into iCloud photos, I can't view any of my photos. There is small print saying "iCloud photos requires ios 8.1 or later..." Does this mean I cannot use iCloud? I am paying for extra storage but where are my pictures?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iCloud photos from a PC, Mac, iOS and web application](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230). So it's conceivable you could use that service even though one of your devices is ineligible to participate due to it not running a supported iOS version.

From a supported web browser, your photos in iCloud are at:

- https://www.icloud.com/#photos

You can review storage at - https://www.icloud.com/#settings

Comment: Thank you bmike. I've tried the links you've shown. When I log in to my account and go to Photos, there's still nothing there. I can see my contacts are saved but no photos.

Comment: @Sally Then you likely have no photos stored directly in iCloud. They could be embedded as part of a device backup - but you'd need to restore that backup to a device to know if photos are there...